# Omiting parenthesis in Scala

Tags: scala, methods, implicit

I'm running some experiments with implicit classes and came up with the following issue. Here it is:

```
object Main extends App {
  implicit class IntExtractor(str: String){
    def extractInt(i: Int): Int = i + str.##
  }

  implicit class ArrayCreator(i: Int){
    def -->(ii: Int): Array[Int] = Array[Int](i, ii)
    def createArray(ii: Int): Array[Int] = Array[Int](i, ii) 
  }

  "STR" extractInt 10 createArray 11   //fine
  ("STR" extractInt 10) --> 11         //fine
  "STR" extractInt 10 --> 11           //compile-error
}
```

[***DEMO***](http://ideone.com/qNduyo)

What's is the reason for not compiling the example with `-->` method? I thought `-->` is a perfectly valid identifier in `Scala`... like any other identifiers.

Comment: And since `-->` worked with first example, you should know that the problem is not with the `-->`. The problem lies in the absence of  those `parentheses`.

Comment: @SarveshKumarSingh Yes, my bad. That's actually easy. Thank you.

Comment: Scala, like most other languages starts to evaluate expressions from the right side. And hence in the case of "operators" with equal precedence the one's on the right are evaluated first. So... your `"STR" extractInt 10 --> 11` is treaded as `"STR" extractInt (10 --> 11)`, which results in your `extractInt` getting the result of `-->` which is an Array as an argument. But `extractInt` expects an `Int` which leads to the compilation error.

Comment: Actually the problem is that they don't have equal precedence. Because the first expression does work.

Comment: @Sarvesh Post that as an answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The precedence of operators in Scala is dependent on the first symbol/character of its name as described here [1](http://scala-lang.org/files/archive/spec/2.11/06-expressions.html#infix-operations), the order of precedence being

- (all letters)
- `|`
- `^`
- `&`
- `=` `!`
- `<` `>`
- `:`
- `+` `-`
- `*` `/` `%`
- (all other special characters)

That's why `"STR" extractInt 10 createArray 11` is parsed as `("STR" extractInt 10) createArray 11` while `"STR" extractInt 10 --> 11` is parsed as `"STR" extractInt (10 --> 11)` which then produces the compile error.